# Laravel "php artisan down" command fails "unable to create file"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am running Laravel 5.1 in a Centos 6.8 VPS.

The problem is when I simply try to run the command `php artisan down` it returns an error message saying the following:

```
 [ErrorException]                                                                                                                 
  touch(): Unable to create file /home/myUser/public_html/laravelProject/storage/framework/down because No such file or directory
```

It looks like its trying to create the "down" file? I don't understand what is going on, perhaps you know what is going on.

Thank you for any help

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/myUser/public_html/laravelProject/storage/framework/` tell you?

Comment: @miken32 No such file or directory. Duh! Thank you, I just created the framework folder and ran the command and it worked. Thank you!